# how to find top highest number in R

Tags: r

I'm new in R coding. I want to find code for this question. Display the city name and the total attendance of the five top-attendance stadiums. I have dataframe worldcupmatches. Please, if anyone can help me out.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not provided us a subset of your data (which is strongly recommended), I will create a tiny dataset with `city` names and `attendance` like so:

```
df = data.frame(city = c("London", "Liverpool", "Manchester", "Birmingham"),
                attendance = c(2390, 1290, 8734, 5433))
```

Then your problem can easily be solved. For example, one of the `base R` approaches is:

```
df[order(df$attendance, decreasing = T), ]
```

You could also use `dplyr` which makes things look a little tidier:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% arrange(desc(attendance))
```

Output of the both methods is your original data, but ordered from the highest to the lowest attendance:

```
        city attendance
3 Manchester       8734
4 Birmingham       5433
1     London       2390
2  Liverpool       1290
```

If you specifically want to display a certain number of cities (or stadiums) with top highest attendance, you could do:

```
df[order(df$attendance, decreasing = T), ][1:3, ] # 1:3 takes the top 3 staidums

        city attendance
3 Manchester       8734
4 Birmingham       5433
1     London       2390
```

Again, `dplyr` approach/code looks much nicer:

```
df %>% slice_max(n = 3, order_by = attendance)

        city attendance
1 Manchester       8734
2 Birmingham       5433
3     London       2390
```

Comment: if you need to "... display he city name and the total attendance ..." either remove the `select()` statement in the last example or specifically extract city and attendance with `select(city, attendance)`. Besides this +1 to @bird for a nice and clean dplyr example.

Comment: @Ray after double-checking with the original post I agree that OP wants to "display the city name and the total attendance". I edited both `base R` and `dplyr` methods. Thanks for the comment. =)